# Volume preference - blocking volume keys

Tags: android

I have seen couple of similar problems with solutions, but I couldn't find one that would work in my situation.

I am making VolumePreference (extending DialogPreference) that let's user choose volume level for some alarm.

In other preference user chooses desired ringtone that is played during alarm. It is also played while user is choosing volume in VolumePreference, so he knows how it actually sounds.

In yet another preference user chooses if alarm should "override" phone's media volume level when playing - I do that, so if user wants to have fixed volume level for alarm, then it shouldn't be affected by changes made by volume keys and so on. 
If user chooses to do that, before starting to play alarm in AlarmActivity, I set volume to max level with AudioManager and intercept all keyDown events of volume keys, restoring volume level after alarm finishes.

Problem is, I can't block volume keys within my VolumePreference as there is no onKeyDown method.

After some checking, I found registerMediaButtonEventReceiver method of AudioManager that "Register a component to be the sole receiver of MEDIA_BUTTON intents.", which I believe could help in my situation (making some empty receiver), and even make volume locking more universal (register when I want to start lock, unregister after unlock), but it is working from API8, while I am making app for API7 - which still hold over 10% of market from what I read, so I would like to stick to it.

Any ideas on how one could block volume changes in PreferenceDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking solution proved to be really simple - one can override onKeyDown method of View created in onCreateDialogView of DialogPreference or set onKeyListener of that View.

First example:

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(mContext)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
                    || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) return true;
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
                    || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) return true;
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
        }
    };
```

Second example (mDialogView is saved reference to layout from first example):

```
mDialogView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
                        || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I have chosen second solution, as I think it is more flexible for two reasons at least

- I can just remove listener to stop blocking volume keys, while in first method I can't
- in first solution I need to decide if I want to block keys input while creating View - not much use if VolumePreference is extending some other Preference that shouldn't block keys input